# Employment gaps

Tags: employment-gaps

Should I quit my job to apply for a 4-month full-stack coding bootcamp (lots of good reviews)? It'll leave a 4-month employment gap on my resume. I already have a 2-year employment gap when I quit another job for grad school.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a gap if you spent the time off work pursuing a degree or in a full-time training.

Whether participating in this specific training makes sense and whether you need to give up your job to participate are completely different questions of course.